# Import utilities into a Groovy script

Tags: groovy

Say I have a folder with two Groovy files:

```
Main.groovy
Utils.groovy
```

I have some methods in the `Utils.groovy` file that I want to use in `Main.groovy`, just so I can reuse them afterwards in other Groovy scripts. So I tried this in `Main.groovy`:

```
import Utils
```

This seems to be working when current working folder is the one where the scripts are located. However, this did not work if I `cd`-ed to some other place, with the error message:

```
unable to resolve class Utils
```

Any way to import the files relative to the script folder, not current working folder? I know I can supply `-cp` or do other things like use a real build tool, but the idea is to be able to just run these.

Comment: How are you running `Main.groovy`?

Comment: @tim_yates Just `groovy Main.groovy`.

Comment: You could run it with a bash script that gets the correct path set up for `-cp`? Is this windows or Linux?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, that's what I alluded to in the last sentence - just wanted to see if I can avoid that. When I have 10 Groovy scripts, I need to make / maintain 10 bash scripts or make some general script with a parameter (so more typing) or thinks like that. Trying to be frugal :) Linux is good, but could do a `.bat` in Windows in the same fashion, but with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both files in the same directory you don't have to import anything. Take a look at this example. I've created in `/tmp` directory 2 files: Utils.groovy and Main.groovy. In Utils.groovy you can find:

```
class Utils {
   def foo() {
      return 2
   }
}
```

In Main.groovy you can find:

```
Utils utils = new Utils()
println utils.foo()
```

All I do is: `groovyc Main.groovy` and then `groovy Main`. The output is:

```
wololock@localhost : /tmp
[1] % groovy Main 
2
```

Then to run it from any directory you're currently in, run:

```
wololock@localhost : /usr
[1] % groovy -cp /tmp /tmp/Main
2
```

Comment: That's true - did not think about that! +1 for reminding me. However as I said, the cwd is not the same as the script folder. For your example, try doing a `cd /usr`, then `groovy /tmp/Main.groovy`.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak OP already knows that: *I know I can supply -cp or do other things like use a real build tool, but the idea is to be able to just run these.*

Comment: Oh, missed that one, thx. I don't see any problem then. Or do I miss something again? :)